# What is a "sticker candidate"?

Tags: united-states, election, parties

I'm looking through old election returns and saw that a candidate in the [1942 Michigan Senate election](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.49015002212018&view=1up&seq=299&skin=2021) is listed as a "sticker candidate".

> [image]

What is a "sticker candidate"?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think it's another name for a write-in candidate. According to [Wikipedia's page on write-in candidates (under the heading *"How to write in the name"*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-in_candidate#How_to_write_in_the_name):

> Some U.S. states and local jurisdictions allow a voter to affix a sticker, with the write-in candidate's name, to the ballot in lieu of actually writing in the candidate's name.

Wikipedia's page on the 1942 Senate elections, under the heading for the state of Michigan list Gerald L. K. Smits (the one from your picture) with the label *(sticker)*, just like in your picture.

On [Wikipedia's page on the 1942 Senate election in Michigan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1942_United_States_Senate_election_in_Michigan) he has the label *(write-in)* instead.

As such, I'd conclude that *(sticker)* indicates he was a write-in candidate.

Comment: That's a good way to ensure the "write" in is actually written legibly and spelled right.  I'd never thought of that before.

Comment: There's a write-in campaign in Buffalo, New York right now (the incumbent Mayor lost his primary and is running as a write-in candidate in the general after his lawsuits to get on the ballot failed) that has ordered [a large quantity of stamps](https://www.wgrz.com/article/news/politics/elections/mayor-browns-campaign-orders-large-amount-of-stamps-for-election-day/71-87bc795b-3d53-4660-9276-e263e7c8b658) to distribute to supporters. Apparently stickers aren't legal in New York for this purpose, but stamps are.